# External javascipt failed to load or is blocked

Tags: support, bug, mathjax, login

[image]When I try to open math.stackexchange.com, mathJax does not load and I see a message saying that the external javascript failed to load or is blocked. As a result, I cannot often log into my stackexchange account or even view the equations. Can anyone please shed some light on this and  what I can do ?(I am using someone else's laptop. The error message appears on my laptop only occasionally- I am using my college WiFi). I am using Windows 7 and the result was the same when I tried to access math.stackexchange or Mathoveroverflow from IE, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome(all updated versions).I do not see any of the tools necessary to attach an image.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem with logging in, or is your problem with the mathematics display? The latter it seems like either your browser is configured too stringently (for MathJax to work it needs to be loaded from "the cloud" from a server that is not directly affiliated with StackExchange), or that you have network problems. Please edit the question to clarify. It helps to include also your browser, operating system, and other information about your computer setup that may be useful for the diagnosis. It also helps to include the exact error messages (or screenshots thereof).

Comment: @WillieWong, please have a look at the question again. I am not able to insert an image here.

Comment: Please upload the image to a hosting site like [imgur](http://imgur.com/). Post the link in the comments here. And flag for moderator attention. We'll insert in the image for you.

Comment: There is a newer version of this question, which received a good answer. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16661/mse-requires-javascript-from-another-domain-which-is-blocked-or-failed-to-load